# Azure autoscale on app service does not scale back DOWN on schedule

Tags: azure, scale, azure-app-service-plans, autoscalemode

I have an Azure AppServicePlan and have enabled Autoscale based on a schedule. The default number of servers is always 1.

During weekdays it should scale up at 12:50pm to 2. Then at 4pm it should scale back DOWN to 1.

It always scales up correctly, but does not scale down at 4pm. It remains on 2 servers. Today it scaled up correctly from 1 to 2 servers at 12:50. However it is now 16:50 and it has remained on 2 servers. It has NOT scaled back down to 1 at the END time of the rule.

The default scale rule is not executing as my CPU is never more than 10% and memory is never more than 58% or so.

This is how my configuration looks:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your average CPU usage at? Your default profile allows for 2 instances so I assume that is the issue.

Comment: No, it's well below the threshold of the default Rule (sorry, should have included that in my original post, *updated*)

Comment: That's quite interesting, you should probably send a ticket to Azure Support (or contact @AzureSupport on twitter)

Comment: Thanks I will try that - I don't have a paid plan so I cannot contact them, but I will tweet them a link to this.

Comment: I have raised a ticket on the MS Azure forums and will come back when they answer